# Dual national treated different to single national in the benefit system

Tags: united-kingdom, government-benefits

I know somebody who put in for a claim for his child's [Disability Living Allowance](https://www.gov.uk/disability-living-allowance-children) (DLA). His child is a dual national, they asked for a copy of the child's passport. The staff confirmed it is because they are British and another nationality rather than British only. My argument is they have no right to do additional checks based on just the fact it is a dual national child and for no other reason, a dual national is regarded British just as much as any other non-dual national. How should he continue? Does anybody know why they ask for additional documentation? two staff have confirmed if it was British only, they wouldn't be asking for this.

Comment: What if a dual national child has no passports?  Has your acquaintance considered asking about that?  There's no law compelling a British citizen in the UK to have a passport, neither a British passport nor a foreign one.

Comment: Does the child in question have a passport for either country? What have they told the agency about the passports? There seems to be a lot of missing information here and nothing about the response to the agency over the passport request. Has the request for the passport been refused? If so how did the agency respond? Just because they requested the passport doesn't mean they won't do anything.

Comment: have they actually been treated differently, or did they just ask for documents?

Comment: they have the documents, they are just upset because they were told the reason they need to show them is because they are dual national.

Comment: Have they actually responded to the request for more documentation? If you are going to get any help you have to explain how they responded to the request and how the agency responded to that as well. Is it a matter of asking for the documents but still processing it if they are not provided? Being a dual national is a valid reason for different process flow

Comment: Well nationality is a protected characteristic under the equality act, so it seems like they should at least have to explain why being a dual national triggers this request (though I don't know the details of the equality act).  I wonder whether it's not a result of misunderstanding the law and the administrative requirements.  Is the child's other nationality of an EEA country or Switzerland?

Comment: @JoeW the question is whether it is lawful for them to make the request.  How the applicant replied to the request is not relevant to whether the request itself was lawful, nor is whether they are willing to grant the DLA if the request is unfulfilled.

Comment: It could be something as simple as the other country is responsible for paying part of the benefits that you are entitled to and it could be to your benefit to provide that data.

Comment: @TigerGuy the request for additional documents is the discriminatory treatment.

Comment: @phoog There is still a lot of information missing from this and for all we know they would process the request and the issue would be partial solved if they just said no to it. All the information that we have is that a request was made and they are upset about it. If we know that the request was made and refused the response that they get will help give proper advice on the next steps. For all we know it could be a step on the form that the workers are following and they could have moved on when told no.

Comment: @phoog what is missing? they were told by two staff members if he was not dual national they wouldn't ask, if he had been British only not British + something else.

Comment: Are they asking for the British passport, the foreign passport, or both?  Is the foreign nationality of an EEA country or Switzerland?

Comment: @phoog no, the other nationality is an Asian country.

Comment: How could they ask for a foreign passport if you are only a citizen of England? Of course they are only asking for the passport of people who would have reason to have a passport from another country.

Comment: @JoeW i thought it was implied I was talking about British passport.

Comment: That is not what I was understanding and that does change things.